# How do you add an eventListener to a htmlCollection that will change the display of another element?

Tags: javascript

Aim : to click box(x) and it opens pop-up(x);

This is my first javascript project, i've done loads of research but i'm still struggling.
The reason I'm using a getElementByClassList is because it returns an array. I would then take the array and get the corresponding pop-up box and change its display settings in css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1 boxes"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="box2 boxes"></div>
        <div class="box3 boxes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup1"></div>
    <div class="popup2"></div>
    <div class="popup3"></div>
    
    <script>
        const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('boxes');
        // i would like to add an eventlistener for each object in the array
        //
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trigger click event for another element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // wait till all the DOM is Loaded, since querying objects at this point they are not there yet.
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes"); // or use getElementsBy...
  
  boxes.forEach(box => { // we are adding a click event listener to each box
    box.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const boxNumber = e.target.className.match(/box(\d)/)[1]; // through a regex we get the box number of the className
      const popup = document.querySelector(`.popup${boxNumber}`);
      
      console.log(popup)
      // do whatever you want with the popup, add a className or whatever to open it :)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1 boxes"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="box2 boxes"></div>
        <div class="box3 boxes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup1"></div>
    <div class="popup2"></div>
    <div class="popup3"></div>
    
    <script>
        const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('boxes');
        // i would like to add an eventlistener for each object in the array
        //
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does this mean? .match(/box(\d)/)[1];

Comment: It is a regex that looks in an string what matches the word `box` continued by a number (`\d`) and its between parenthesis since I want to acess that number with `[1]`, `[0]` of the array returns `box1`, `box2`, `box3`

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
     const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('boxes');
     const popups = document.querySelectorAll(".popups");

     boxes.forEach((box,index)=>box.addEventListener("click",()=>{
     const popup = popups[index]; // This gets the popup based on the box index so you will have to setup the html so that the popup for box1 is the first then popup for box2 second etc.
     
     // Add styles to popup to display it
     // Example
     popup.style.opacity = "1";
     
     })
```

Visit the 'mdn docs' or 'youtube' to learn how the array methods like forEach work

Comment: Thanks, instead of changing the style of the box, how would you change the properties of the pop-up? for example, if i click box1, I would like pop up 1 to appear, and box2 makes pop up 2 appear and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The method getElement**s**ByClassName() indicats that return an array of html objects, in case there exists elements with passed css class.

The first step you have to iterate trough the array object:

```
for (int index = 0; index < boxes.length; index++)
{

}
```

Within for loop access to each element and assign the eventent handle

```
boxes[index].addEventListnener('click', function()
{

});
```

Within the body of declared anonymous function add your code.